# Different extension configuration in a multidomain TYPO3 setup?

Tags: configuration, typo3

I wrote an extension and was wondering, if it is possible to have seperate settings in a multidomain environment.
As far as I can see, the extension configuration (defined via ext_conf_template.txt) is global per TYPO3 installation (compare TYPO3-docs [here](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ConfigurationOptions/Index.html)).

Is there a possibility to define them seperately for each domain, that is served by the (single) TYPO3 installation?!

(of course, there's a kind of workaround by defining them via typoscript and define them seperately in the root template of each domain, but I'd like to make the settings configurable with the nice built-in UI in the backend).

Comment: Maybe another possibility could be... using constants and constant editor